# How to generate multiple state spaces from arrays in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, function-handle, state-space

I would like to ask how to create **multiple state-spaces from arrays**.

**Input is:**

```
A1toA100 (100xn double)
B1toB100 (100xp double)
C1toC100 (100xn double)
D1toD100 (100xp double)
```

**Example:**

```
A1toA10 =

   -0.5909
   -0.4178
   -0.3412
   -0.2954
   -0.2643
   -0.2412
   -0.2233
   -0.2089
   -0.1970
   -0.1869

>> B1toB10

B1toB10 =

   33.3333
   33.3333
   33.3333
   33.3333
   33.3333
   33.3333
   33.3333
   33.3333
   33.3333
   33.3333

>> C1toC10

C1toC10 =

     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1

>> D1toD10

D1toD10 =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

Where each of these contains a hundred of matrices of respective type (A,B,C or D).

**Output should be:**

```
SS1toSS100 (100x ss)
```

Where there would be a state space corresponding to each set of matrices.

**Example for the first system:**

With this code

```
ss([-0.5909],[33.3333],[1],[0])
```

I get a correct output. Four numbers, one system <1x1 ss>. This:

```
ans =

  a = 
            x1
   x1  -0.5909

  b = 
          u1
   x1  33.33

  c = 
       x1
   y1   1

  d = 
       u1
   y1   0
```

However with this code:

```
for i=1:2
    pom=[-0.5909 33.3333 1 0]
    SS1toSS10(i)=ss(pom(1),pom(2),pom(3),pom(4));
end
```

Although I should get 2 systems identical to the first one, I get this instead:

```
 SS1toSS10

SS1toSS10 =

  a = 
            x1       x2
   x1  -0.5909        0
   x2        0  -0.5909

  b = 
          u1     u2
   x1  33.33      0
   x2      0  33.33

  c = 
       x1  x2
   y1   1   1

  d = 
       u1  u2
   y1   0   0

Continuous-time state-space model.
```

Which is a wrong answer.

**Approach 1:**

```
for i=1:length(A1toA100)
    SS1toSS100(i)=ss(A1toA100(i),B1toB100,C1toC100,D1toD100);
end
```

This has generated 100 state spaces with matrix dimensions of 200x200, which is wrong, as I would expect dimensions of 2x2. Obviously the dimensions of entire matrices are considered.

Example output for Example input vectors:

```
S1toS10(1,1).a

-0,417825056426464  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   -0,341152729998142  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   -0,295446930748805  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   -0,264255768359200  0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   -0,241231408801990  0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   -0,223336886965331  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   -0,208912528213232  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -0,196964620499203  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -0,186857045774452  0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -0,590893861497609

S1toS10(1,1).b

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
33,3333333333333

S1toS10(1,1).c

1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

S1toS10(1,1).d

0
```

**Approach 2:**

```
for i=1:length(A1toA100)
    SS1toSS100(i)=arrayfun(@ss,A1toA100(i),B1toB100,C1toC100,D1toD100);
end
```

Ends up with this error.

Error using arrayfun
ss output type is not currently implemented.

Thank you for your help,
Petr

Comment: why not: `SS1toSS100(i)=ss(A1toA100(i),B1toB100(i),C1toC100(i),D1toD100(i));` ?

Comment: Considering I have a 1st order system (which is just 4 numbers) and apply on it this function.
Result will be that each state space has a matrix A with dimensions 200x200 (or whatever the dimensions of A1toA100 are). That is not correct.

In addition to that, I have discovered that each of the A matrices of each of the state spaces is identical.
So I guess that somehow the whole matrix is taken into the state space function.

Comment: please post examples of the elements of your input vector.

Comment: you can edit your question. What you posted are probably no row vectors? And still: what about my suggestion in my first comment? It seems you access the whole array of arrays and not just one in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, it's there. (No, they are row vectors, I've just edited them not to take up that much space, as I wasn't aware of editable question).
Your first suggestion is the same as my first approach, is it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I get your problem! Your last edit was essential.

The only way to store multiple state space models in one variable is a `struct`. Therefore your loop has to look like:

```
SS1toSS100(100) = struct;   %pre-allocation
for ii=1:100
    temp_ss = ss( A1toA100(ii) , B1toB100(ii) , C1toC100(ii) , D1toD100(ii) );
    SS1toSS100(ii) = struct('ss',temp_ss);
end
```

or even shorter:

```
SS1toSS100(100) = struct;   %pre-allocation
for ii=1:100
    SS1toSS100(ii).ss = ss( A1toA100(ii) , B1toB100(ii) , C1toC100(ii) , D1toD100(ii) );
end
```

which gives you a struct with 100 `ss` objects.

If you now want to access the 5th one for example, type:

```
SS1toSS100(5).ss
```

and you get

```
ans =

  a = 
            x1
   x1  -0.5909

  b = 
          u1
   x1  33.33

  c = 
       x1
   y1   1

  d = 
       u1
   y1   0

Continuous-time state-space model.
```

*PS: don't use `i` as iteration variable it's a internal Matlab variable and reserved for complex numbers*

Comment: They are from system identification. This particular case is a first order system (order of the system is equal to the dimension of matrix A), but still correct.

I plugged in your code, however it ends up with this error.

Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Comment: again and again: use `SS1toSS100(i)=ss(A1toA100(i),B1toB100(i),C1toC100(i),D1toD100(i))` in your loop. -.-

Comment: It seems that I am not emphasizing this enough. I have posted the matrices in ss(in question), which I get by using this code you are posting(and my first approach).

Comment: I have just edited it in the question. (like if you put 4 numbers into ss function and get an output).

Comment: again and again: use `SS1toSS100(i)=ss(A1toA100(i),B1toB100(i),C1toC100(i),D1toD100(i))` in your loop.

Comment: Sorry, I am using it, but it produces wrong answer. I am adding one more thing in the original question - hope it will be clear now.